# Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.get: IO error: .../LOCK: No further details

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build some chrome extension.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Translator Api</title>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        Key: <input type="text" id="key">
        <br>
        Password: <input type="text" id="pass">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var key, pass, submit, d = document;
    key = d.getElementById('key');
    pass = d.getElementById('pass');
    submit = d.getElementById('submit');
    chrome.storage.sync.get('key', function (items) {
        if (items.key)
            key.value = items.key;
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.get('pass', function (items) {
        if (items.pass)
            pass.value = items.pass;
    });
    submit.onclick = function () {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            key : key.value,
            pass : pass.value
        });
    };
});
```

manifest

```json
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "name" : "bla bla",
    "description" : "bla bla",
    "version" : "1.0",

    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png",
        "default_popup" : "index.html"
    },

    "permissions" : [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

But I'm getting this error when I open the popup window:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.get: IO error: .../LOCK: No further details

When I check for permissions for the extension it says:

> No special permissions for that extension

I tried to search in google for a solution for this problem , but couldn't to find anything related.

I reloaded the extension, remove and add it, but still don't work.

if someone could direct me to a solution I will be grateful.

Comment: Sounds like a concurrency bug in the browser. Simply get both keys at once: ['key', 'pass']

Comment: @wOxxOm didn't help, But thanks for the helpful comment (I was realy wondering how to pull two items at once)

Comment: Judging by chromium source code this error occurs when the file is corrupted. Or maybe it cannot be opened due to being locked by another process. Try to remove the extension and then install it so that the database is deleted and recreated. The issue may also be caused by incompatibility with some antivirus that locks files.

Comment: @wOxxOm I already tried to reinstall the extension , didn't help, about the antivirus, actually i tried it on a mac computer without permissions, I will try it when I'll arrive home, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to your application it is caused by some google extension please close the google extension one by one [see this video for refrence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsKYuBn7YpQ)

Comment: Answer is correct, in my case google translator extension was doing problem. Thanks @sadab-khan